# merge two sets with considering the order of each one (in Python)

Tags: python, set

I have two variables i, j that they show the length of two sets one and two, like len(one)=i and len(two)=j. Now, I want to merge these two sets such that having the ordered permutations of each set. I need also to index each new set in Python.

for example:
one includes the first i upper case letters, and two includes lowercase letters

```
 len(one) = i  
    len(two) = j 
expected outputs = {'abABC...', 'aAbBC...', 'aABcC...', 'aABCb...',...}
```

I have tried the following code but it does not work. I will be thankful if anyone can help.

```
    from functools import reduce
    from itertools import combinations

    def assign(v, p):
        v[p[0]] = p[1]
        return v

    def interp(word1, word2, size):
        return (''.join(reduce(assign, zip(comb1, word1), zip(comb2, word2)))
                for comb1, comb2 in zip(combinations(range(size), len(word1)),
                                        combinations(range(size), len(word2))))

    print('\n'.join(interp("ABC", "ab", 5)))
```

Comment: don't use reduce for side-effects: `reduce(assign`

Comment: Sets are unordered in Python, so there is no way you can preserve the order of `ABC` and `ab` as suggested by your expected output. Change your input to lists and you would then have a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function that merges the first item of one of the two lists with the combinations from the rest of the list recursively:

```
def merge(a, b):
    if a and b:
        for (first, *rest), other in (a, b), (b, a):
            yield from ([first, *merged] for merged in merge(rest, other))
    elif a or b:
        yield a or b
```

so that:

```
for combination in merge(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b']):
    print(''.join(combination))
```

outputs:

```
ABCab
ABabC
ABaCb
AabBC
AaBCb
AaBbC
abABC
aABCb
aABbC
aAbBC
```

Note that sets are unordered in Python, so there is no way you can preserve the order of `ABC` and `ab` as suggested by your expected output if your input are sets. The example given here assumes your input and output to be lists instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @blhsing. I have another question. If the number of letters in the sets is variable, what I can do?

Comment: Glad to be of help. My answer does not make any assumption about the number of letters in the lists, so you can use any number of letters. Also, can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Comment: I've already marked it. Thank you. I mean how I can assume the letters as a variable like i?

Comment: I don't think you've marked the answer as accepted since the grey check mark next to the answer would've turned green if you did. As for making the set of letters a variable you can just make it like the `one` and `two` variables that you posted in your question.

Comment: I just did it. Sorry, I am new to this website. As for my question, I mean that In another part of my code, I get the number of letters of one and two as i and j.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what you mean. Isn't the number of letters in `one` simply `len(one)`? Why do you need another variable to specify its length?

Comment: You're right. I can have the number of letters by len, but how I can use merge function by the len of letters?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean by "use merge function by the len of letters". Can you update your question with an example of function input parameters and the expected output?

Comment: I see your updated question, but with just the lengths of the letters, how are you supposed to know what letters they are? Are they always alphabetic sequences A, B, C, etc., one in uppercase, and the other in lowercase?

Comment: actually, they are not letters. They can be every set of objects. To simplify the problem, I have assumed them as two sets of letters, one in uppercase and one in lowercase.

Comment: Exactly. So how are you supposed to derive these objects from just a length? You simply cannot know what items to iterate through if your input are just a couple of numbers.

Comment: This is the problem. Can I generate the permutations by assuming the sets as two sets of numbers?

Comment: No, I mean, how do you know what objects are in set `one` and set `two` if you are just given the lengths of them? The question makes no sense.

Comment: We can assume that I have two sets of objects, it doesn't matter what they are, letters, numbers, ...I only know the length of them. The thing that I need is the permutations of these two sets.

Comment: A permutation of two sets by definition requires the objects within the sets to be permuted. Without the objects in the sets there's no permutation to speak of. Please clearly define the process of your "permutation" given just the lengths of the sets with a step-by-step example if you think I'm not interpreting your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing the [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from `itertools`:

```
one = set(['A', 'B', 'C'])
two = set(['a', 'b'])

from itertools import permutations, tee, filterfalse, chain

def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)

iter_1 = ((i, 1) for i in one)
iter_2 = ((i, 2) for i in two)

for c in permutations(chain(iter_1, iter_2), 5):
    p1, p2 = map(list, partition(lambda k: k[1] == 1, c))
    if sorted(p1, key=lambda k: k[0]) == p1 and sorted(p2, key=lambda k: k[0]) == p2:
        print(''.join(i[0] for i in c))
```

Prints:

```
ABCab
ABaCb
ABabC
AaBCb
AaBbC
AabBC
aABCb
aABbC
aAbBC
abABC
```

Comment: It's wasteful and inefficient to generate all the possible permutations only to throw away most of them, whose orders do not match those of the inputs. Brute-force solutions should only be used as a very last resort.